# Проблема с разрешением экрана в Linux

Tags: linux, debian, lightdm, mate

Имеется ОС Linux Debian 10 с MATE на борту. Имеется такой симптом: если загрузится экран авторизации и компьютер оставить, чтобы он "ушёл в блокировку" (погас экран), то после выхода из этого состояния сбросится разрешение и будет некорректно до перезагрузки ПК. Перезагрузка lightdm и X сервера не помогает.